# Add files to playable DVD Mac

Tags: macos, dvd, burning

I have a DVD that was created in iDVD, I don't have the source, just the DVD with the VIDEO_TS and AUDIO_TS folders. When I stick it in my DVD player, I get a nice menu and can play one of 4 home movies. The total size of the files on the DVD is 2.28 GB. I would like to add about 200 photos (size of all photos is 1.2 GB) to the DVD and then distribute the DVD to family members. I would like it to play just like it does now when inserted into a DVD player, but when inserted into a computer they would be able to browse files and look at or copy the photos. Is this possible, and if so, How?

I have an iMac running Snow Leopard, and iDVD 7.1.1. I'd prefer to do this with the installed software, but if that is not possible and there is 3rd party software for the mac that would be ok too. In either case step by step instructions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally doable. In fact you'll totally avoid iDVD (or any 3rd party software) in doing so. I've done this a handful of times since about 10.4 with no issues, playback or otherwise. Though, keep in mind, not all DVD players appreciate all media.

### Basically you'll be doing the following:

- Copying the DVD (e.g., VIDEO_TS)
- Creating/organizing the new/extra content
- Creating a new disc image containing both

### And this is how (at least how I'd do it):

1. "Rip" your DVD (Omitting for brevity's sake. Plus, you have your VIDEO_TS folder already.)
2. Create a new directory on your Desktop.

   - `mkdir -p ~/Desktop/MY_NEW_DVD`
   - `cd ~/Desktop/MY_NEW_DVD`
3. Copy/move your original assets

   - `cp -r path/to/ORIGINAL_DVD/VIDEO_TS .`
4. Copy the directory with your photos

   - `cp -r ~/Pictures/Family2011 .`
5. Create a UDF-compatible image of MY_NEW_DVD

   - `hdiutil makehybrid -udf -udf-volume-name NAME_OF_MY_NEW_DVD -o ~/Desktop/MY_NEW_DVD.iso .`
6. Test the image we just created

   - Mount the image: `hdiutil attach ~/Desktop/MY_NEW_DVD.iso`
   - Open it with DVD Player.app: `open -a /Applications/DVD\ Player.app /Volumes/NAME_OF_MY_NEW_DVD/`
   - Check a few of the photos: `open -a /Applications/Preview.app /Volumes/NAME_OF_MY_NEW_DVD/Family2011/1.jpg`
   - Unmount the volume: `hdiutil detach /Volumes/NAME_OF_MY_NEW_DVD/`
7. Burn our image

   - `hdiutil burn ~/Desktop/MY_NEW_DVD.iso`

### Result

```
~/Desktop/
    MY_NEW_DVD.iso
    MY_NEW_DVD/
        Family2011/
            1.jpg
            2.jpg
            3.jpg
            (etc…)
        VIDEO_TS/
            VIDEO_TS.BUP
            VIDEO_TS.IFO
            VTS_01_0.BUP
            VTS_01_0.IFO
            VTS_01_0.VOB
            VTS_01_1.VOB
            (etc…)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - worked perfectly! So this may not auto-play when inserted in some DVD Players?

Comment: Glad to hear it, Scott. As far as I know, autoplay is a device feature, so you're unlikely to run into issues with that on set-top/standalone units. Also, regarding UDF compatibility, I've always been just fine without specifying a version (`hditutil`'s default is 1.5), but you may want to add the `-udf-version 1.02` flag to step 5.

Answer (score 0):

Once a DVD is finalized, it's no longer possible to edit its contents.

DVDs need to be finalized to play them in DVD players, and I suspect that already happened through the use of iDVD.

Comment: Is there a way to "re finalize" by copying the VIDEO_TS, AUDIO_TS, folders, adding a PHOTOS folder and finalizing again?